# What does the phrase "turn him in" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

This context comes from the movie "Annie Hall" with Woody Allen and Diane Keaton.

“It reminds me of that old joke- you know, a guy walks into a psychiatrist's office and says, hey doc, my brother's crazy! He thinks he's a chicken. Then the doc says, why don't you **turn him in**? Then the guy says, I would but I need the eggs. I guess that's how I feel about relationships. They're totally crazy, irrational, and absurd, but we keep going through it because we need the eggs.”

I know this phrase in the sense of:

**"turn in"**

5. To surrender, deliver, or give information about someone or oneself to the authorities, typically the police. In this usage, a noun or pronoun can be used between "turn" and "in."
   *I was so racked with guilt over the accident that I turned myself in to police*.(Farlex Dictionary of Idioms).

I'm not sure if this is the sense conveyed in the scene from the movie though. There is another definition that I suspect might be more fitting here.

**"turn in"**

to submit or **refer someone** or something to someone or a group, especially in some official capacity. *The good citizen turned his neighbor in for watering his lawn during the wrong hours. *I turned in the report to the treasurer**.(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.

The second definition says **to refer someone**. Does the psychiatrist from the joke say "why don't you refer him to a psychiatrist"(or him for that matter)?

Comment: This one: _refer someone or something to someone or a group, e.g. local mental health services_.

Comment: In fact in most, if not all places, health services would not care about a person behaving oddly unless they were likely to harm themselves or other people, so there would be nowhere to turn him in.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense as a joke. Unless they were planning to turn him in to a farmer.

Comment: @StuartF (say it quietly!) or, heaven forbid, a fricassee.

Comment: Newer/longer/better versions of the joke (@MichaelHarvey) have things like: *Dr: how long has this been going on? / Guy: About a year / Dr: why didn't you come to me sooner / Guy: we needed the eggs* (or something to like *Dr: I think we can cure that / Guy: but we need the eggs*)

Comment: @ChrisH - it's kind of generic. General practitioner working late at night on paperwork - knock on front door - man says he needs help - thinks he is a moth - GP says you need a psychiatrist not a GP, why did you knock here? Man says he knows but he saw the light bulb through the window as he walked past in the street.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I have a child with a book full of this sort of thing.  The chicken one is more absurd than the moth, because the patient actually produces eggs rather than just behaving like a chicken.  Of course there are other versions too

Comment: @ChrisH - An uncle used to get the New Yorker magazine now and then, and aged about 7 I once saw a cartoon showing a sorrowful looking puppy at what was obviously a vet's clinic. The vet is saying to a woman, "He thinks he's a nightdress case". My mother had to explain it to me.

Comment: @ChrisH - I just told the OP's joke to my 10 year old niece, and she chuckled, and then said 'I don't think I'd like the kind of 'eggs' that a man might produce'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey my daughter keeps chickens at her mum's, and came close to buying a sign reading "chickens - the pet that poops breakfast".  She's 9; it sounds like young minds think alike.

Comment: @ChrisH - my wife is vegetarian but is OK with dairy and eggs. Early in our relationship she said she tried not to think about where they come from. I thought she meant the precise part of the hen's anatomy but no, she meant she preferred to pretend they grow on some kind of bush.

Answer (score 4):

It is the first defintion.  "Deliver to the authorities".  In this specfic case you would understand it to be "Deliver him to a secure mental hospital (insane asylum)"

Of course in real life, that's not how mental health crises are managed, but this is a joke.

Comment: These days I think we are supposed to just call them 'hospitals', but at home, when no-one else is there, my wife and I talk about 'the nut house' and _chez les dingues_.